# MVC4 WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(..) Not Creating Tables

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am trying to create the "webpages_" tables so that I can use them with an existing database with simplemembership. I have added the following line to my Global.asax.cs file

WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyDbContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "EmailAddress", true);

I've also added the Webmatrix.WebData dll and appropriate using statement to my Global.asax.cs file.

Long story short the tables are not being created and there is no error message. I've set a breakpoint and the code is executing in Global.asax. Also a page that checks Websecurity.IsAuthenticated correctly redirects to the home page.

I would like to know if there is a sql script I can run to create the tables manually and if possible, what could be preventing the tables from being created if they do not exist?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:** 
I think the issue may have been caused by this link in my Global.asax.cs file

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
```

Comment: Have you verified the connection is pointing at the expected database?  I have encountered situations similar to yours and the reason there was no error is that the tables were created somewhere other than the expected location.

Comment: I checked the app_data folder and there weren't any stray databases. What I did was create a new MVC4 site and changed the default connection to my existing DB, editied the InitializeDatabaseConnection under the Filters folder and visited the accounts page. Still curious why the weren't created in my app though.

Comment: The first parameter in the IntializeDatabaseConnection method is the name of the connection string. Do you have a connection string in your web.config named "MyDbContext"? If so provide it in your question.

Comment: Is this `Code first`?